# Align multiline content with :before and :after content

Tags: html, css

I have a text which I have used CSS to prepend with quotation tags. When the text reaches a new line, it doesn't align after the quotation mark symbol, but before

```css
div {
  width: 240px;
}

p:before {
  content: "“";
  font-size: 30px;
}

p:after {
  content: "”";
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="quote">This is some text that represents a quote that is rather long and splits into multiple lines</p>
</div>
```

I would like it to look like this

[image]

Can this be done using `:before` and `:after` or should I look for a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position your `:before` and its parent `p` as `absolute` and `relative` respectively to get it done. Check below snippet for reference.

```css
div {
  width: 240px;
}

p {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

p:before {
  content: "“";
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

p:after {
  content: "”";
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="quote">This is some text that represents a quote that is rather long and splits into multiple lines</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
div {
  width: 240px;
}
p:before,
p:after {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p:before {
  content: "“";
  font-size: 30px;
}

p:after {
  content: "”";
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="quote">This is some text that represents a quote that is rather long and splits into multiple lines</p>
</div>
```